# other ax users can't see customizations till a day or two

Tags: dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I am having this problem on Microsoft dynamics AX2012, whenever I code new customizations (form changing, adding buttons, or even changing standard code on tables..etc. the other users can't see these changes and even codes in the background like tables methods aren't executed. it always takes 24h to 48h then it's working fine.
I tried adding a simple `info` message when a button on a form is clicked, for example, for me, it works well, but for other users nothing happens, we tried closing the software and reopening it, still nothing. if I access MorphX Development Tools with this user and go to the button code, I can see it, usually, if I do a useless change on the code, like adding blank space, and compile again for that user, then it works

anyone has an idea on how to fix this? is there some cache clearing or enable auto-updating of the interface..etc?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, objects are cached, which is one of the many reasons why you shouldn't do customizations directly in environments used by other users.

An AOS restart usually clears the cache (note that in multi-AOS environments, all AOS must be restarted). In some cases, you also need to recompile the application.

There are also tools in the IDE that allow you to clear the some caches, but I have rarely used those successfully. See "Old application objects" and the various "Refresh" tools in [MorphX Development Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/morphx-development-tools)

Comment: thank you, very helpful, restarting AOS was the answer